# DAPP Gas Fees, how often is it charged?

Tags: dapps

Do you have to pay gas each time you deploy a DAPP and if so does that mean you have to pay gas for updates as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you have to pay gas each time you deploy a DAPP

Yes, Gas is needed each time you deploy a contract or send transaction on Ethereum. If your Dapp tries to interact with blockchain for sending tx or deploying and interacting with contracts, then you will have to pay

> Does that mean you have to pay gas for updates as well?

Updates to you contract will need gas as they are also transactions to the contract.